# ARTOOLKIT Installation on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, augmented-reality

Is there any easy way to install ARTOOLKIT on windows 7 and visual studio 2010 ? All the help available is for VS2006 and windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

Build steps:

(1) Unpack the ARToolKit zip to a convenient location. This location will be referred to below as {ARToolKit}.

(2) Unpack the DSVideoLib zip into {ARToolKit}. Make sure that the directory is named "DSVL".

(3) Copy the files DSVL.dll and DSVLd.dll from {ARToolKit}\DSVL\bin into {ARToolKit}\bin.

(4) Install GLUT, put *.h and *.lib in GLUT SDK in VStudio folder ( include\GL\glut.h and lib\glut32.lib）

(5) Run the script {ARToolKit}\Configure.win32.bat to create include\AR\config.h.

(6) Open the ARToolKit.sln file (VS.NET) or ARToolkit.dsw file (VS6).

(7) Build the toolkit.

The VRML renderering library and example (libARvrml & simpleVRML) are optional builds:

(8) Unpack the OpenVRML zip into {ARToolKit}.

(9) Copy js32.dll from {ARToolKit}\OpenVRML\bin into {ARToolKit}\bin.

(10) Enable the libARvrml and simpleVRML projects in the VS configuration manager and build.

Some tips:

(1) You may need this tutorial
http://www.artoolworks.com/support/library/ARToolKit_tutorial_1:_First_simple_ARToolKit_scene

(2) Camera info in \bin\DATA\WDM_camera_flipV.xml . Change the friendly_name to your video device. Try AMCap.exe to get your video device name.(e.g. mine is friendly_name="USB Video Device")

Comment: Thanks, your final point worked! Earlier my sample programs were crashing once they were executed. It's working fine now! cheers!

Comment: I agree, the camera info saved my bacon as well.  Nice work @Alpha!

Answer (score 0):

This question is old. Newer version of ARToolkit has an installer that comes with many required packages. This is what I wrote based on ARToolkit 5.3.1

```
Requirements: 
visual studio 2013

Installing OpenCV

1. Download OpenCV 2.4.11 http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-win/2.4.11/opencv-2.4.11.exe and extract
2. Copy all lib files from extracted opencv to visual studio:  opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib
3. Copy header folder from opencv\build\include (there are two folders: opencv, opencv2) to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include
4. Change windows environment PATH environment variable by adding your opencv bin path: J:\UTDallas\PhDThesis\Resources\artoolkit\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin
5. (Notice that we use x86 compile in the guide)

Installing Artoolkit

6. Download http://www.artoolkit.org/dist/artoolkit5/5.3/ARToolKit%20v5.3.1R2%20Setup%20(bin-win32-vs120).exe And install
7. Run C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\Configure-win32.vbs
8. Open solution from C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\VisualStudio\vs120\ in Visual Studio 2013
9. For project calib_camera, set Opencv links. Right click on Project, select properties, find Linker from the left, select input. Change Additional Dependencies by removing old OpenCV and adding newer version of OpenCV. For debug mode use debug links (you may only change version of the current. This is the complete list of opencv 2.4.11 lib files)

opencv_calib3d2411d.lib
opencv_contrib2411d.lib
opencv_core2411d.lib
opencv_features2d2411d.lib
opencv_flann2411d.lib
opencv_gpu2411d.lib
opencv_highgui2411d.lib
opencv_imgproc2411d.lib
opencv_legacy2411d.lib
opencv_ml2411d.lib
opencv_nonfree2411d.lib
opencv_objdetect2411d.lib
opencv_ocl2411d.lib
opencv_photo2411d.lib
opencv_stitching2411d.lib
opencv_superres2411d.lib
opencv_ts2411d.lib
opencv_video2411d.lib
opencv_videostab2411d.lib

For release mode use release links (you may only change version of the current. This is the complete list of opencv 2.4.11 lib files):

opencv_calib3d2411.lib
opencv_contrib2411.lib
opencv_core2411.lib
opencv_features2d2411.lib
opencv_flann2411.lib
opencv_gpu2411.lib
opencv_highgui2411.lib
opencv_imgproc2411.lib
opencv_legacy2411.lib
opencv_ml2411.lib
opencv_nonfree2411.lib
opencv_objdetect2411.lib
opencv_ocl2411.lib
opencv_photo2411d.lib
opencv_stitching2411.lib
opencv_superres2411.lib
opencv_ts2411.lib
opencv_video2411.lib
opencv_videostab2411.lib

10. Compile the solution. (Only VRML project won't compile)
11. Run examples from C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\bin


Installing QuickTime
12. Download and install QuickTime for windows: https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/quicktime/031-43075-20160107-c0844134-b3cd-11e5-b1c0-43ca8d551951/quicktimeinstaller.exe
13. Download QuickTime 7.3 SDK from Apple Developer (You will need apple developer account) https://developer.apple.com/downloads/: http://adcdownload.apple.com/QuickTime/quicktime_7.3_sdk_for_windows/quicktimesdk.zip
14. Run C:\Program Files (x86)\ARToolKit5\VisualStudio\vs120\Patch QuickTime 7.3 SDK\PatchQuickTime73SDK.vbs to configure for this version
```